# Rename [azure-msi] to [azure-managed-identity]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [azure-msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-msi) tag is currently used for questions related to [Managed Identities for Azure resources](http://aka.ms/azuremanagedidentity)

When we first introduced the product, it was called Azure AD managed service identity. Although we didn't give it an official acronym, everybody gravitated to MSI, which caused a lot of confusion due to the fact that the MSI acronym is already well recognized elsewhere. 9 months ago, we updated our naming to be more clear, and it's how we landed with Azure Managed Identity.

I'm looking to update the tag to [azure-managed-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-managed-identity) to reflect our correct naming.

I would love to rename the tag to azure-managed identity. And additionally, create a synonym for azure-msi to point to azure-managed-identity. That way the actual tag has the correct name. Is that possible?

UPDATE 6/27: 
Additional context and justification:

- At the beginning of my post, there's a link to [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) that clearly says: **Managed identities for Azure resources is the new name for the service formerly known as Managed Service Identity (MSI)**
- [Article for when Managed Service Identity was first introduced to the world](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/keep-credentials-out-of-code-introducing-azure-ad-managed-service-identity/)
- [Exact moment in my Microsoft Ignite 2018 session, where I call out the name change and reasons for it.](https://youtu.be/C1FzhSieMgQ?t=2524)
- I agree that people are still using azure-msi, which is why I'm asking for a synonym to be created as well.

Comment: Moderators can do this easily, but you didn't provide a sufficient justification. Why is it currently called "MSI"? That nomenclature appears in recent questions, as well. Can you convince me that MSI means "managed identity"? It certainly doesn't seem to be the same. There's no "s" in "managed identity".

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not that knowledgeable about this subject, but I do know it's the same thing: Managed Service Identity. And apparently the name has indeed changed to just managed identity now. Seems like a reasonable request, even though the post is quite limited.

Comment: I think a synonym would be better here, people might have trouble finding the tag if it's renamed.

Comment: @ArturoLucatero-MSFT I've moved your comments to your question as that is what mods will read when they get to your post. Please verify if that still captures your intent. If not please [edit] to further improve.

Comment: @CodyGray: Any chance you can help me out with this? Per the edits, is that sufficient justification?

Comment: @CodyGray: Any pointers? Really hoping to get this updated soon. :) thanks!

Comment: Pestering me repeatedly with pings is not really an effective way of persuading me that this is a good idea. All I see here is rene's edits attempting to make sense of your proposal. I don't see any actual evidence being offered here. There are no links to support the claims. There's no reference to questions on this site or  posts elsewhere on the Internet showing how users commonly refer to these technologies. I don't know if you think I'm just supposed to believe what you say because you have "MSFT" after your user name, but that's really not enough.

Comment: @CodyGray: I appreciate your straight response. I asked a 2nd time after 10 days, because I never got a yes or no on whether I provided sufficient justification. 
If you click on the link at the beginning of the post, there's a clear note that states the name change. Regardless, I have updated the post to include additional sources of justification. 

Please let me know if that's enough justification, if there's something else I can provide. 
Thanks,
-Arturo

Comment: After reviewing the documentation and name change, this looks like a sound and reasonable solution. I renamed [azure-msi] to [tag:azure-managed-identity] (90 questions). The tag synonym mapping [azure-msi] → [azure-managed-identity] should take care of any contingencies.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Thank you very much! Really appreciated, and glad to have this completed.